# Validation function not working

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to write a validation statement on a button to say that if 2 specific textfields are blank and they click on the button, then return the message "This field is valid"

Here is the code that I currently have:

```
    function validateButton(){
    if (tfState.getValue()!=''){
        if (tfCity.getValue()!='') return true;
        else return 'This value is not valid.';
    }
    else return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `getValue();` is, but assuming that `tfState` and `tfCity` are references to DOM nodes:

```
function validateButton(){
    if (tfState.value !='' && tfCity.value != ''){
        return true;
    }
    return 'This value is not valid.';
}
```

Comment: I tried this way and I am getting an Uncaught TypeError saying "has no method 'toLowerCase'"

Comment: Can you be more specific, `toLowerCase` is not mentioned anywhere in your example.

Comment: This is the full message that I am receiving and I am not adding toLowerCase anywhere in my code. Uncaught TypeError: Object function validateButton(){
    if (tfState.value !='' && tfCity.value != ''){
        return true;
    }
    return 'This value is not valid.';
} has no method 'toLowerCase'

Comment: Without more information, it appears that your calling function is expecting a string to be returned.

Comment: I made a simple mistake on the button. I was using a listener instead of a validator for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you want

```
    function validateButton(){
    if ((tfState.val().length != 0) && (tfCity.val().length != 0))
       return true;

    }
      else return 'This value is not valid.';
}
```